# Post on Tumblr without Text - HTML

Tags: html, post, tumblr, permalinks

I'm making a new blog and I'm having a big issue. So far I could create the front page, but when I try to post something it doesn't display anything.

This is the code I have:

```
{block:Posts}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Date}
  <a />
{/block:Date}{/block:PermalinkPage}
</a>
</div>
{/block:Posts}
```

This is the post/permalink: http://lifeafterpixel.tumblr.com/post/109350024127/here-1

As you can see, only the background appears as such the topbar. I need to show the text. It should appear only the text, images, audio, and anything like a normal post. Why is it not happening?

Comment: You need to include the relevant code in the question

Comment: The code is on: http://pastebin.com/Mti1dwNd  
That's the full code of that page. I dont know where the problem is. I know the text is not showing on the post.. Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: In the question (not a link), and only the relevant code!

Comment: Well, I dont know exactly what would be the relevant code. So I'll make the question on other way. What is the code to create text when you click on a permalink? ( That part of the code is missing ).

Comment: According to this: http://lifeafterpixel.tumblr.com/archive you have only made a single post. What I would do is make other test posts. Images, Video, Quote, Audio etc. And then run this test again. Some themes don't display certain post types. I don't think that is the problem, but if you can try creating more posts and resubmit your question it might help.

Comment: Did you create the theme yourself? It is possible there is an open tag somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To show the title and body for a Text Post on the permalink page:

```
{block:Posts}
{block:PermalinkPage}

{block:Title}
<h2>{Title}</h2>
{/block:Title}

{Body}

{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Posts}
```

However, in the spirit of StackOverflow, this question should be closed as too broad. The OP is asking for code for all post types, which is the bulk of the theme.

I suggest the OP reads the [How to create a custom HTML theme](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes) by Tumblr before posting more questions.